# while (i<=sqrt(static_cast<double>(n))

Tags: c++, primes, sqrt

In the "C++ Without Fear: A Beginner's Guide That Makes You Feel Smart" book, in Chapter (2): Decisions, Decisions, you can see this lin of code as part of the prime number program:

```
while (i<=sqrt(static_cast<double>(n))
```

Provided that "i" was initialized to "2", and "n" is the user's input.

Why are we comparing to the "sqrt" of "n" and not to "n" itself?

Thanks.

Comment: this "depends" on what is happening in the loop - without that, the answer would be - "well, the author felt like it!"

Comment: Beyond the current answer, you may find this informative:  http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/56715.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because if a number has factors other than itself and 1, then at least one of those factors will be less than the number's sqrt.

Answer (score 6):

Because you won't get any factors for non-primes which are > sqrt(n) (you would have already found the other, smaller factor).

It's a really bad test though, it would be much better to write it as:

```
while (i*i <= n)
```

Comment: Actually, since we're iterating i, we don't want to square i on each iteration. n could be very large and that would be an extra multiplication per iteration. All we need to do is take the sqrt out of the loop test. Of cource, since the result of the sqrt is loop invariant, it would be optimized out by the compiler anyway.

Comment: @Thomas: good point - that would be a better solution. Of course it's a terrible algorithm for finding primes anyway, so a better choice of algorithm would be even more effective.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (i<=sqrt(static_cast<double>(n))
```

Is equivalent to

```
while(n >= i*i)
```

Why the author choose the first solution may depend on other parts of the code.

Answer (score 0):

The code goes like this:

```
i = 2;
while (i <= sqrt(static_cast<double>(n)) {
  if (n % i == 0) is_prime = false;
  i++;
}
```

So the loop is checking if *n* is divisible by *i* without remainder. Obviously, only has to check this up to (and including) the square root of *n* (because if `n / p = q` then also `n / q = p`).

Answer (score 0):

Algorithmically it is correct to check possible factors up to the square root of your target.

If N is a number that may or may not be prime, if there are no factors (not including 1) up to sqrt(N) then N must be prime. sqrt(N) itself may well be its only prime factor (eg 9 which is 3*3).

If we are going to test to see if 17 is prime, we know that sqrt(17) is just above 4. 2, 3 and 4 do not divide into 17 so it must be prime as 5 is greater.

This must be the case because 17/5 will be less than 5 and would have to be a factor too, but we know there are no factors less than 5.

Programmatically of course the code is not optimal, as you would not use doubles and square-roots but something like (i*i <= N)